# Unable to Update Chromedriver on Centos 7

Tags: centos7, yum, repository, google-chrome

I have chromedriver installed via yum using the below setup. Chromedriver still shows up as version `2.30` whereas the latest version available is `2.36`, is there any way to check what version is in the repo or can I manually update the chromedriver outside of yum?

**Created repo file**

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
```

**Configuration**

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

**Ran installs**

```
yum install google-chrome-stable
yum install chromedriver
```

Answer (score 1):

To get an overview of the packages provided by a specific repository you can use `repoquery`.

```
repoquery --repoid=google-chrome --all
```

For a more detailed output add `--info`.

```
repoquery --repoid=google-chrome --all --info
```

From `yum info chromedriver` it seems this package is provided by the EPEL repository. While the download for Chromedriver 2.36 is available at Google, the package maintainer at EPEL for this package did not package this release yet.
Alternatively you can download the latest release directly from Google.